# How can I make the fields in my views "searchable?"

Tags: views, search

So I have several views on my website with specific fields shown in table format. The search bar only searches through specific content, like pages, and basic pages. How can I modify the views or the search function to make it so that words typed into the search bar will search through the text entered for each field displayed in the views?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out the [Search API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api). It's an extremely powerful extension to regular Drupal search, allowing you to use many advanced search backends and also integrates with Views to allow you to search on any field you wish.